# MS SQL Server where exist same rows

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have table like this

```
TABLE1

DATE                     NAME  PRODUCT    VERSION       Colour    SIZE    ID
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Mouse      12            Pink      3      461
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Mouse      12            Pink      3      446
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Mouse      13            Pink      3      487
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Honey      6             Red       5      476
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Honey      6             Blue      5      774
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Shoe       6             Black     5      487
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Dog        5             Black     7      1874
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Dog        5             Black     7      999
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Pet        689           Red       9      855
2017-08-02 01:30:20.000  Eva   Mouse      12            Pink      3      461
2017-08-02 01:30:20.000  Eva   Mouse      12            Pink      3      446
```

And the result should look like this:

```
TABLE1

DATE                     NAME  PRODUCT    VERSION       Colour    SIZE    ID
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Mouse      12            Ping      3      446
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Mouse      13            Ping      3      487
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Honey      6             Red       5      476
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Shoe       6             Black     5      487
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Dog        5             Black     7      1874
2017-08-03 01:30:20.000  Bob   Pet        689           Red       9      855
2017-08-02 01:30:20.000  Eva   Mouse      12            Pink      3      446
```

Main thing i am interest for is : `Product` AND `Version`

If is different something else should by deleted rows which contain Same `PRODUCT` AND `VERSION`

Problem is with column `ID` where I have always different `ID` numbers, but with Different `NAME` I have Same `ID`

Comment: Table have 100000 rows. This is example of thing.

Comment: `select * from (select row_number()over(partition by NAME,PRODUCT,VERSION order by ID desc) rn,* from.. ) a where rn = 1`

Comment: What if the dates, names, colours or sizes are different as well?

Comment: So you don't care about the value of ID? My do you delete the `(Mouse|12)` row with `ID=461` yet keep two such records with `ID=446`

Comment: Zohar Peled- Keep NAME , product and version. After this will be Group By and COUNT.

Comment: user2877959  yes priority is Keep NAME , product and version. After this will be Group By and COUNT

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking on how to remove the duplicate values are are you asking on how to select with group by? BTW, removing the duplicates is just the first step, you also want to create a unique index so that it's impossible to get duplicate data in the future.

Comment: Zohar Peled -This is first step of SSIS second is GROUP BY AND COUNT which i know how to add column and COUNT products with version.. I can not calc. now because i have duplicity of products

Answer (score 0):

There are examples if you need just to select such data or if you need to delete it:

```
create table #test
(
   [DATE] DateTime2(7),
   [NAME] VARCHAR(200),
   [PRODUCT] VARCHAR(200),
   [VERSION] INT,
   [Colour] VARCHAR(200),
   [SIZE] INT,
   [ID] INT
);

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Mouse',      12,            'Pink',      3,      461);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Mouse',      12,            'Pink',      3,      446);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Mouse',      13,            'Pink',      3,      487);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Honey',      6,             'Red',       5,      476);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Honey',      6,             'Blue',      5,      774);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Shoe',       6,             'Black',     5,      487);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Dog',        5,             'Black',     7,      1874);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Dog',        5,             'Black',     7,      999);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-03 01:30:20.000',  'Bob',   'Pet',        689,           'Red',       9,      855);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-02 01:30:20.000',  'Eva',   'Mouse',      12,            'Pink',      3,      461);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2017-08-02 01:30:20.000',  'Eva',   'Mouse',      12,            'Pink',      3,      446);


SELECT 
   [DATE] ,
   [NAME],
   [PRODUCT],
   [VERSION],
   [Colour],
   [SIZE],
   [ID] 
FROM (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PRODUCT], [VERSION] ORDER BY [ID]) rn
FROM #test
) a
WHERE rn = 1;


DELETE FROM #test WHERE ID IN (SELECT 
   [ID] 
FROM (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PRODUCT], [VERSION] ORDER BY [ID]) rn
FROM #test
) a
WHERE rn > 1);

SELECT * FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Comment: But EVA gone is well.

Comment: Then clarify the question. You can control uniqueness by specifying the right column list in PARTITION BY section